# how to put the JSON data into UICollectionView in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, json

I try to get the Images from a [JSON URL](http://ielmo.xtreemhost.com/array.php) and place on `UICollectionView`

but i don't how to get images from JSON

```
 #import "ViewController.h"
    #import "CustomCell.h"
    @interface ViewController ()
    {

        NSArray *arrayOfImages;
        NSArray *arrayOfDescriptions;
        NSMutableArray *json;
        NSString *img;
        NSMutableData *webData;
         NSURLConnection *connection;
    }
    @end


    @implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        /**/
        [[self myCollectionView]setDataSource:self];
        [[self myCollectionView]setDelegate:self];

        NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ielmo.xtreemhost.com/array.php"];


        NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSURLRequest *req=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        connection=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];

        if(connection)
        {
            NSLog(@"Connected");

            webData=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
        }
  [super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [webData setLength:0];

}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [webData appendData:data];

}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error is");
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{



    NSMutableArray *al=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];

    NSLog(@"all array isn %@",al);




    NSData* myData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:al];

    NSLog(@"Data is data%@",myData);

   NSError *error;

    json=(NSMutableArray*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Data is arrayjson%@",json);

    for(int i=0;i<json.count;i++)
    {
        img=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[json objectAtIndex:i]];
        NSLog(@"Data is arrayimage%@",img);
    }


   NSURL *urlOne=[NSURL URLWithString:img];
    NSLog(@"Data is arrayurl%@",urlOne);
    NSData *newData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlOne];

    UIImageView *imaegView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(38,0, 76, 96)];


    [imaegView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:newData]];

    [self.myCollectionView addSubview:imaegView];


    [[self myCollectionView]reloadData];

}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{

    return  1;
}


-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return  [arrayOfImages count];
}


-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell=[ collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [[cell myImage]setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]]];
   // [[cell myLabel]setText:[arrayOfDescriptions objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
    return cell;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

i tried this code but in my output image are not display in my `collectionView` 
please tell me how to retrieve images from json to My-collection VIew

Comment: Did you convert JSON to image?

Comment: can you paste the information in "al" array

Comment: where did you get **arrayOfImages** ?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Thansk for replay i don't know how to convert JSON to image and then place  image  in COllectionView

Comment: @CharanGiri all array of data placed in al but i don't know how place array data(al) into COllectionView

Comment: what ever the information  NSLog(@"all array isn %@",al); provides in console please paste it, based on that we can help you

Comment: where are you assigning information to arrayOfImages Array

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi  data in al(all images),arrayOfImage(NSArray reference) is an empty array i want to  place this "al" data into my arrayOfImage

Comment: Did you log the count of your `arrayOfImages` after the data is recieved?

Comment: It would be quite unusual to transmit an image of any size as JSON.  And if it is, it would be Base64-encoded.

Comment: And you need to show us the error messages and/or JSON values you're receiving.

Comment: @Hot Licks it's not showing any error message but images not adding in collectionView

Comment: What does the JSON look like?

Comment: `...(NSMutableArray*)[NSJSONSe...` Casting to mutable does not make an array mutable.  Use the correct option to get a mutable array from JSONObjectWithData.

Comment: Where do you ever create and initialize `arrayOfImages`??

Comment: (You're in pretty far over your head.)

Comment: @HotLicks i have Url(http://ielmo.xtreemhost.com/array.php) in url have 5 image i want 5 image display on UiCollectionView

Comment: That is an array of image URLs.  You need to load the URLs and make the data available to the collection view in the proper fashion.  But you don't understand how a collection view works (among other things), so you have problems.

Answer (score 1):

*As your `JSON` contains Image.*

It must be encoded while transmitting mostly in Base64. Now you need to decode it to form `NSData`.

Once you have converted it to `NSData` then you can easily form an `UIImage` from it, after this you can show the image on collection view.

Comment: Vaiday thanks for Replay Can you give the example on This Process

Comment: @PavanAlapati: Just search `send uiimage json`...you will get lots of answers.

Comment: i am try to converted data but images or not display in my collectionView please check my code